# AWS Pinpoint, can you request local phone number(long code) with local area code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, sms, twilio

I got a random phone number when I requested a long code. It would be nice if I can pick from a list of available local numbers. Does AWS plan to support it in future or do I have to request a service limit change?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It should be asked on Amazon website support page

Answer (score 1):

When you purchase a long code through the Pinpoint console, we assign a long code based on our inventory of phone numbers in the selected country.

I recommend [opening a new Pinpoint SMS Service Limit Increase case](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-awssupport-long-code.html) in the AWS Support Center. In the case, mention your desired area codes. We can't guarantee that we'll be able to provide a number with the specified area code, but we'll make our best effort to find one for you.

Thanks for using Amazon Pinpoint!

Brent @ AWS